# Android SQLite database is not updating when multiple updates are fired

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update

I am trying to update the sql database in Android.

```
public boolean updatepasswordbySimcardnumber(String simcard, String password) { 
          mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
          mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();         
         Cursor mCursor = null;
         int retvalue = 0;

         mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                   KEY_IDNUM, KEY_SIMCARD, KEY_DESCRIPTION, KEY_MODEL, KEY_TIMEINSTANCE, KEY_PASSWORD}, 
                   null, null, null, null, null);

         for(mCursor.moveToFirst(); !mCursor.isAfterLast(); mCursor.moveToNext()){
             if(mCursor.getString(2).equals(simcard)){
                   ContentValues updatevalue = new ContentValues();          
                   updatevalue.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);             
                   long colId = mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
                   retvalue =  mDb.update(SQLITE_TABLE, updatevalue, KEY_ROWID + "=?",new String[] { String.valueOf(colId) });// + colId, null);
                   break;
             }
         }
         mDbHelper.close();
         return retvalue > 0;
     }
```

But the password has never been updated. The retvalue is always 0. What could be wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
long colId = mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
```

It should be

```
long colId = mCursor.getLong(getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID));
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are doing wrong. You have to set begin transaction if you have multiple records to insert into database.

You can use database transactions for this.

**How you can use database transaction in Android**

```
If you want to start the transaction there is a method beginTransaction()
If you want to commit the transaction there is a method setTransactionSuccessful() which will commit the values in the database
If you had start the transaction you need to close the transaction so there is a method endTransaction() which will end your database transaction
```

**Now there are two main points**

```
If you want to set transaction successful you need to write setTransactionSuccessful() and then endTransaction() after beginTransaction()
If you want to rollback your transaction then you need to endTransaction() without committing the transaction by setTransactionSuccessful().
```

EDIT:

EX.:

```
db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            // update table
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();

        }catch {
            //Error in between database transaction 
        }finally {
                db.endTransaction();

        }
```